# How to create simple module in magento admin?

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.9

How can I display a simple form like first name and last name in admin HTML (admin side) in magento 1.9.0? For creating a simple module.

[image]

I also create the simple menu for display form so plz explains me then how I will show there simple form.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO helper appreciate it when you show effort of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow some tutorials on building admin modules in Magento to achieve what you are looking for.
A nice start would be http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/category/magento-blogs/admin-module-development/